# How can i change the orientation of the caption inside the tab in the tabsheet in delphi?

Tags: delphi, orientation, caption, tpagecontrol, ttabsheet

I am trying to make a pagecontrol using delphi, the problem is when i switch the tabsheet's position to the sides the caption change too and i want it to be horizontal, any clue about how to do this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The standard control doesn't support this

Comment: IMHO, page controls with tabs on the sides or bottom shouldn't be used after Win 9x, partly because they look very bad with visual themes. It feels like a legacy feature that hasn't received any attention or love since XP was introduced in 2001.

Comment: I had a quick look at it, and it seems like you can make some progress by owner-drawing the tabs. I set `OwnerDraw` to `True`, increased the `TabHeight` and drew the horisontal text in the `OnDrawTab` handler. However, this still makes the tabs too thick. `var
  R: TRect;
  S: string;
begin
  R := Rect;
  S := PageControl1.Pages[TabIndex].Caption;
  Control.Canvas.TextRect(R, S, [tfSingleLine, tfCenter, tfVerticalCenter, tfEndEllipsis]);`

Comment: I think your best option is to use a different control.

Comment: (I don't quite see why this Q is downvoted. IMHO, the Q is reasonable.)

Comment: I am sorry if my question isn't clear enough, im not a programmer i am just. Trying to learn by my self and i am not used to this forum

Comment: @Andreas *...this still makes the tabs too thick* But you can reduce `TabWidth`. Something like 25 seems reasonable (depending on font).

Comment: @Tom: Ah, didn't try that. Good point. Still, I am not convinced this is a good idea anyway...

Comment: @Andreas You are right about problems with visual themes.